# Angularjs multiple sub menus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a sub menu using angularjs.

Which will work fine for one sub menu, but I have multiple on the same page.

I'm trying to do this the "angular way" without using jQuery, which is proving difficult.

[jsBin: http://jsbin.com/cimiw/3/edit](http://jsbin.com/cimiw/3/edit)

See code below.

**Javascript:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.subMenu = false;

        $scope.toggleSubMenu = function () {
            $scope.subMenu = !$scope.subMenu;
        };
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p>{{subMenu}}</p>
    <br>
  <ul>
        <li ng-class="{active: subMenu}"> <a href="#hello" ng-click="toggleSubMenu()">hello</a>

            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#foo" ng-click="toggleSubMenu()">foo</a>

            <ul>
                <li>bar</li>
                <li>bar</li>
                <li>bar</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#bar" ng-click="toggleSubMenu()">bar</a>

            <ul>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>foo</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul > li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
ul > li > ul {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}
ul > li.active > ul {
    display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: Can't You maintain an array of values for subMenu ?? $scope.subMenu = [false, false, false] ??;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array for the submenu:

```
function MyCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.subMenu = [];    // default is false

    $scope.toggleSubMenu = function (index) {
        $scope.subMenu[index] = !$scope.subMenu[index];
    };
}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active: subMenu[0]}"> <a href="#hello" ng-click="toggleSubMenu(0)">hello</a>
        <ul>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
            <li>test</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: subMenu[1]}"> <a href="#foo" ng-click="toggleSubMenu(1)">foo</a>
        <ul>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>bar</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: subMenu[2]}"> <a href="#bar" ng-click="toggleSubMenu(2)">bar</a>
        <ul>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>foo</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/caluyere/1/edit).